# What is difference between PORTABLE and Machine Independent?

Tags: java, asp.net, .net

This might be silly question but I am confused between portable and machine independent.
What is Java, c#.net : portable or machine independent?

Comment: These terms mean different things to different people, so I don't think you can get a clear answer to this question.

Comment: @StephenC Is it different for different technologies like java, .net, php and others?

Comment: What "it" are you talking about?  If those terms are meaningful, they *should* mean the same thing for different technologies.  The fact that you feel the need to qualify them by the technology merely illustrates how ill-defined they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is difference between PORTABLE and Machine Independent?

There is no real answer to this.  It depends on whose definitions of "portable" and "machine independent" you chose to accept.  (I could pick a pair of definitions that I agree with and compare those.  But I don't think that's objective.)

---

> What is Java, c#.net : portable or machine independent?

You could argue that Java and C# are neither portable or machine independent.

- A Java or C# program only runs on a platform with a JVM or CLR implementation, and a "compliant" implementation of the respective standard libraries.  Ergo, the languages are not machine independent (in the literal sense).
- There are many examples of Java (and I'm sure C#) programs that behave differently on different implementations of Java / C#.  Sometimes it is due to differences in runtime libraries and/or the host operating system.  Sometimes it is due to invalid assumptions on the part of the programmer.  But the point is that Java / C# software often requires porting work.  Ergo, they are not portable (in the literal sense.)

Answer (score 3):

**Machine Independence**

Machine independence refers to the idea of software that can be executed irrespective of the machine on which it executes. A piece of Machine **dependent** software might be something written to use, say assembly instructions that are specific to a certain architecture. For example, if you write a C++ application with inline assembly that relies on special processor instructions such as for example, SIMD instructions, then that peice of software is machine dependent because it has specific machine requirements - it can only work on a machine that supports that specific required SIMD instruction set.

In contrast, C# and Java compile to bytecode that is executed by a virtual machine which takes that bytecode and executes it as native code directly on the processor. In this case the virtual machine is machine **dependent** because it will execute against the specific hardware it is written for - for example, only a 32 bit Intel processor, or an ARM Smartphone. The Java and C# applications that run on the virtual machine however are machine **independent** because they care not what the underlying platform is, as long as there is a virtual machine to translate to the underlying paltform for them. That abstraction layer, the virtual machine, helps separate the application from the underlying hardware and that is the reason why those applications can be machine **independent**.

**Portability**

Portability is a separate but related concept, it is a broad term that covers a number of possibilities. A piece of software is portable simply if it can be built and executed or simply executed on more than one platform. This means that machine **independent** software is inherently portable as it has to be by nature.

There are broadly two facets to portability - hardware portability, and software portability. Ignoring for the moment .NET implementations such as Mono and focussing purely on Microsoft's .NET implementation it is fair to say that .NET is hardware portable because it can be executed on any hardware that supports the .NET runtime, however because Microsoft's implementation is only available on Windows and Windows descended operating systems it is fair to say that it is not particularly software portable - without Mono it cannot be executed on Mac OS X or Linux. In contrast, Java could be said to be both hardware portable and software portable because it can run on multiple operating systems like Windows, OS X, Linux hence it is software portable, and hardware portable because it can run on different hardware architectures such as ARM, x86 and x64.

Finally, there is also the question of language portability. Many would argue that although a C++ application compiled for Windows will not natively execute on Linux, it is possible to write C++ code in such a way that the same set of source code can be compiled on both Linux and Windows with no changes - this means that you can port the same application to different operating systems simply by just compiling it as is. In this respect we can say that whilst a compiled C++ application is not portable, the source code for a C++ application can be portable. This applies to a number of other languages including C.

**Disclaimer**

This is a somewhat simplified explanation and there are many edge cases that break these rules which make it such a complex and subjective subject - for example it is possible to write a Java application that is machine dependent if for example you use the Java native interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Portable means that you can run this programm without any installation.

Machine independent means that the same code can be executed on different OS.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5796366/2381238) question could be helpfull, too.

Comment: So based on this definition java is presumably machine independent? I assume whether its portable or not depends on how its distributed?

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a particularly correct answer. The term portability when contrasted and compared to machine independence has nothing to do with whether or not installation is required. Machine independence is also more to do with executing across hardware architectures than software platforms also.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting):

> Software is portable when the cost of porting it to a new platform is
>   less than the cost of writing it from scratch. The lower the cost of
>   porting software, relative to its implementation cost, the more
>   portable it is said to be.

Machine-independent software, on the other hand, does not need any work to be ran on another machine (ex. from Windows to Mac OS). It is by this definition also highly portable.

Comment: The wikipedia article suggests a different interpretation of portable software http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application

Comment: @RichardTingle I'm fairly sure OP wants to know about the broader term of the two (portable as in software in general rather than portable as in you can run it from an USB-stick), seeing OP is comparing portable with machine independent. As your link says: "Portable apps are distinct from software portability..." Good point, though.